# How to resolve location of %UserProfile% programmatically in C++?

Tags: c++, windows, profile

I'd like to find the directory of the current user profile programmatically in C++.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[SHGetSpecialFolderLocation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762203(VS.85).aspx) is the best way to get at most of the special paths on Windows. Passed `CSIDL_PROFILE` it should retrieve the folder you are interested in.

If you are actually interested in the contents of the %UserProfile% environment variable you could try [ExpandEnvironmentStrings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724265(VS.85).aspx)

Answer (score 4):

Simplest way on Windows & Linux:

```
char *szBuff;
szBuff=std::getenv("USERPROFILE");  //Returning value of %USERPROFILE%
```

Answer (score 2):

To cover all user profile scenarios in Windows Vista and up there is SHGetKnownFolderPath.  [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb776911(VS.85).aspx) is the link to the docs page on it and related functions.